# String Object. Clarification needed

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

Say i have the following line in my program:

```
jobSetupErrors.append("abc");
```

In the case above where jobSetupErrors is a StringBuilder(), what i see happen is:

1. New String Object is created and assigned value "abc"
2. value of that String object is assigned to the existing StringBuilder object

If that is correct, and I add 1 more line ...

```
jobSetupErrors.append("abc");
logger.info("abc");
```

In the above example are we creating String object **separately** 2 times?

If so, would it be more proper to do something like this?

```
String a = "abc";
jobSetupErrors.append(a);
logger.info(a);
```

Is this a better approach? Please advise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To help find out, I wrote a class like the following:

```
class Test {
  String a = "abc" ;
  StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder() ;

  public void normal() {
    buffer.append( "abc" ) ;
    buffer.append( "abc" ) ;
  }

  public void clever() {
    buffer.append( a ) ;
    buffer.append( a ) ;
  }
}
```

If we compile this, and then run javap over it to extract the bytecode:

```
14:09:58 :: javap $ javap -c Test
Compiled from "Test.java"
class Test extends java.lang.Object{
java.lang.String a;

java.lang.StringBuilder buffer;

Test();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   aload_0
   5:   ldc #2; //String abc
   7:   putfield    #3; //Field a:Ljava/lang/String;
   10:  aload_0
   11:  new #4; //class java/lang/StringBuilder
   14:  dup
   15:  invokespecial   #5; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
   18:  putfield    #6; //Field buffer:Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   21:  return

public void normal();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   getfield    #6; //Field buffer:Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   4:   ldc #2; //String abc
   6:   invokevirtual   #7; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   9:   pop
   10:  aload_0
   11:  getfield    #6; //Field buffer:Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   14:  ldc #2; //String abc
   16:  invokevirtual   #7; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   19:  pop
   20:  return

public void clever();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   getfield    #6; //Field buffer:Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   4:   aload_0
   5:   getfield    #3; //Field a:Ljava/lang/String;
   8:   invokevirtual   #7; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   11:  pop
   12:  aload_0
   13:  getfield    #6; //Field buffer:Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   16:  aload_0
   17:  getfield    #3; //Field a:Ljava/lang/String;
   20:  invokevirtual   #7; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   23:  pop
   24:  return

}
```

We can see 2 things.

First, the `normal` method is using the same String instance for both of those calls (indeed it is the same literal as is set to the `a` member variable of this class in the initialisation block)

And secondly, the `clever` method is longer than the `normal` one.  This is because extra steps are required to fetch the property out of the class.

So the moral of the story is that 99% of the time, Java does things the right way on it's own, and theres no need in trying to be clever ;-)  (and javap is a really cool tool for when you want to know exactly what's going on)

Comment: whoops! ;-)  can you tell what I'm *supposed* to be doing? ;-)

Comment: you should use a local variable instead of a field in `clever` if comparing the length of code; but anyway, the question was mainly about creating Strings and, as can be seen by your example, there is only one String object involved!

Comment: With a local variable, `clever` is still longer, as you have an additional `astore_1` operation to get the interned String into the variable

Answer (score 8):

> In the above example are we creating
>   String object separately 2 times?

No, because in Java String literals (anything in double-quotes) are interned.  What this means is that both of those lines are referring to the same `String`, so no further optimization is necessary.

In your second example, you are only creating an extra reference to the same `String`, but this is what Java has already done for you by placing a reference to it in something called the string pool.  This happens the first time it sees "abc"; the second time, it checks the pool and finds that "abc" already exists, so it is replaced with the same reference as the first one.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning for more information on String interning.